# MySQL HELP - Need to print from three tables of all classes with less than six students enrolled in them

Tags: mysql, sql

The directions are "Print the course names, course numbers and section numbers of all classes with less than six students enrolled in them."

I have come up with two query's and was wondering if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong or if you can guide me on getting the results. I tried running both of these query's but am not getting any results. I don't exactly know where to put the <6 statement in the second Query.

Here are my tables:

```
Student(sid,sname,sex,age,year,qpa)
Dept(dname,numphds)
Prof (pname,dname)
Course (cno,cname,dname)
Major(dname,sid)
Section(dname,cno,sectno,pname)
Enroll(sid,grade,dname,cno,sectno)

CREATE TABLE course (
 cno INT, 
 cname VARCHAR(100), 
 dname VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO course VALUES ( 302, 'Intro to Programming', 'Computer Sciences' );
INSERT INTO course VALUES ( 310, 'Thermodynamics', 'Chemical Engineering' );
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT course.cname, course.cno, enroll.sectno, COUNT (*)
FROM course 
JOIN enroll on enroll.cno = course.cno AND enroll.sid = student.sid
WHERE COUNT(*)<6;
GROUP BY cname, cno, sectno;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT course.cname, course.cno, enroll.cno, enroll.sectno, COUNT (*)
FROM course, enroll, student 
WHERE course.cno = enroll.cno AND enroll.sid = student.sid
GROUP BY cname, cno, sectno;
```

I am testing this Query to run my program:

```
SELECT course.cname, course.cno, enroll.sectno, COUNT (*)
FROM course 
JOIN enroll on enroll.cno = course.cno AND enroll.sid = student.sid
GROUP BY cname, cno, sectno
HAVING COUNT(*)<6;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move the count to a `HAVING` clause. `WHERE` is for filtering the incoming data (from the tables). The remaining data is processed, and in your case aggregated (count). After that, you can filter those aggregation results using the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT course.cname, course.cno, enroll.sectno, COUNT (*)
FROM course 
JOIN enroll on enroll.cno = course.cno AND enroll.sid = student.sid
GROUP BY cname, cno, sectno
HAVING COUNT(*)>6
```

See [**Having vs. Where Clause**](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/having-vs-where-clause/).

Also note that you had a semicolon halfway your query. That basically divided the query into two queries of which one was silly and the other one plainly invalid. Please use a proper tool that will not just return 'nothing', but will show actual error messages case of a syntax error, otherwise debugging will be very cumbersome.

{edit}

After the discussion, and your modified question, I think the problem is you don't have any students yet (or at least not linked to a course at all. Also, `> 6` should be `< 6`. The query would be:

```
SELECT c.cname, c.cno, e.sectno, COUNT(e.sid) as studentcount
FROM course c
LEFT JOIN enroll e on e.cno = c.cno
GROUP BY c.cname, c.cno, e.sectno
HAVING COUNT(e.sid) < 6
```

A couple of things were fixed here:

- `JOIN` was changed to `LEFT JOIN`, so the course is still returned if no `enroll` records at all exist for it.
- `COUNT(*)` was changed to `COUNT(enroll.sid)`, so it will return 0 if no students are enrolled in this course (otherwise it will return 1 since it counts 'any' field, including those of the course itself).
- `> 6` was changed to `< 6` because you want to have courses with a small number of students.
- The join of `enroll.sid` to `student.sid` was removed. This join was incomplete. The condition was there, but you didn't include the student table in the query at all, and it made the query invalid. You don't need the student table, since you just have to count student ids, which are also in `enroll`, so I left out that join completely.
- I referenced the table (alias) with the field names in the `GROUP BY` clause as well, otherwise you might get an 'ambiguous column name' error, although I'm not sure how MySQL handles this situation. Having a tablename or alias everywhere makes it more readable anyway.
- I added aliases to the table (not needed, but I think it's more readable. Just an opinion.)

The remaining question is whether you need to group by `e.sectno`, but that's for you to figure out. :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that extra semicolon and explaining the WHERE for filtering. Okay, so I changed my WHERE clause to HAVING and am getting an error message of "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM course JOIN enroll on enroll.cno = course.cno AND enroll.sid = studen' at line 1." Don't I need to use the enroll.sid and student.sid in order to get a count of students enrolled in these classes?

Comment: I was silly enough to move the line but not change `WHERE` to `HAVING. I fixed that now.

Comment: Thank you @GolezTrol. I moved the line and changed the syntax, but still have no results coming through. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe there is no combination of `course.cname, course.cno, enroll.sectno` that occurs more than 6 times. If you leave out the `HAVING` clause completely, you get all results to check that. To make that inspection even easier, add `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` at the end of the query, to show to highest counting combinations first.

Comment: Or should `> 6` be `< 6`? I copied it from the question, but reading it again, I think it is wrong.

Comment: You are right, it should be <6. Sorry about that. However, I tried running both the <6 and 'ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC' and still no results are populating. I wonder if it has to do with my rows. I have single quotes on the course names; do you think that has something to do with it? I will edit my original question to show you what I mean.

Comment: Ahh, I think you don't have any students at all linked to the cource. There were some other issues with the query as well. I think I fixed them all, and provided a list of fixes in the updated answer.